# Layer Text Between Background Color Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I have a block of text and it want it to be above the block's background color and below the block's background image.  I know I could just create multiple blocks and `z-index` them.  I'm wanting to keep the code as clean as possible and not have a bunch of unnecessary stuff.

I'm guessing that the answer is "no", but maybe you guys know something I do (maybe a nifty new background property or JavaScript function).

HTML Code:

```
<section role="main" id="content">
    <h1 class="pageheading">Home Page</h1>
</section>
```

CSS Code:

```
#content {
    background-color:#69583b;
    background-image:url(tattoo-256x256.png);
    background-position:center bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Obviously, as it stands, the text "Home Page" sits on top of the image.

The logical thought would simply be to use `<img>` and `position:absolute` it, but, again, that's not my intention.  I know multiple, other, ways it can be done.  I'm just trying to find out if I can do it, this way.

Comment: _"I have a block of text and it want it to be above the block's background color and below the block's background image."_ You lost me at the first sentence. How can the text be be below the image?

Comment: The text stays at top of the bg, what do you want to say? If you want to say text should be below the bg then use -1 index than bg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a CSS pseudo class. (I've added in opacity just as part of the demo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#content {
    background-color:#69583b;
    background-position:center bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#content::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/256x256);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<section role="main" id="content">
    <h1 class="pageheading">Home Page</h1>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed. Either is fine.

Comment: I knew about `::after` and `::before` (and have used them, in the past), but forgot about them.  It worked, perfectly.  For some reason, `background-repeat` wasn't being used.  I had to move it into `#content::after`.  Now, I have just one instance of the image and it's on top of the text.

Comment: I just realized that the positioning and repeating was being over-ridden by `background:`.  It should be `background-image:`, so that `background-position:` and `background-repeat:` keep working.